# Alternate row with value from IN operator

Tags: oracle

Is this possible?

I have a sample query:

```
select vehicle_name 
from   vehicles
where  vehicle_name in ('TOYO', 'HOND');
```

I may have a lot vehicle_name in the `IN` operator clause. The result it returns is in the screenshot given below (screenshot 1).
What I want is in the second screenshot (screenshot 2) where first row should be HOND and second row should be TOYO. (based on alphabetical order) Third row should be HOND and fourth row should be TOYO. so on and so forth. In other words, two HOND or two TOYO should not come one after the other until the end of the result where no alternate vehicle_name is found.

Thanks,

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you want to interleave the results, do a `ROW_NUMBER` partitioned by vehicle_name, and then order by that rownunber and vehicle name.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the analytic function `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate sequence numbers separately for each `vehicle_name` and use that for ordering. You don't need to add the function to `SELECT` - you can use it directly in `ORDER BY`.

```
SELECT   vehicle_name
FROM     vehicles
WHERE    vehicle_name in ('HOND', 'TOYO')
ORDER BY row_number() over (partition by vehicle_name order by null), vehicle_name
;
```

Comment: You don't need to SELECT row_number(), you can still use it directly in ORDER BY. Please see my edits, and edit further if needed. Also, note that - once you `partition by vehicle_name`, ordering by the same is equivalent to no ordering at all (obviously all the rows IN A PARTITION will have THE SAME vehicle name!) In these cases, it is best to make that very clear, by writing `order by NULL` - that shows explicitly that we don't care **how** the rows are ordered, they just need to be ordered.

Comment: @mathguy - The `ORDER BY` including `, vehicle_name` is correct for deterministic results.  Without it two records will have a row number of `1` *(one `'TOYO'` and one `'HOND'`)* and there will be no ***guarantee*** that these two rows will always be returned in the same order.  Adding the `, vehicle_name` ensures that the `'HOND'` always comes fist, as in the example.

Comment: @MatBailie - Of course. I was referring to the `order by` sub-clause in the analytic function `row_number()` - **there** the ordering by `vehicle_name` is meaningless, since `row_number` partitions by `vehicle_name` first. I didn't mean that the `vehicle_name` used as the second sort in the `ORDER BY` clause of the query itself is not needed. (Note how I edited the solution, you will still see it there!)